# power query - shareable excel file that pulls data from common source

Tags: excel, database, connection, powerbi

I am making an excel sheet that pulls data from an online resource that we (a team of 6) put in a common folder on our company sharepoint folder.

When I choose 'get data' and direct the link to the sharepoint folder, it doesnt show the latest file. It shows about a month old files.

So, to work around I synced the sharepoint folder to my harddrive and connected to that and when I 'get data' then it shows the latest file. But the problem with the work around is that when I share this excel sheet amongst the group then the link to the sharepoint folder would be my local hdd address.

Is there a way to make the link in such a way that any team member would be able to see the latest file?